# When updating GTM data layer, how to delete old data?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need to update data Layer after ajax call is made.

We are on product category page, initial data layer code looks like this:

```
var dataLayer = [({
    "categoryProducts": [{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Golden Bridge Bicycle Tour",
        "sku": "bicycle-tour",
        "gender": false,
        "category": "All Tours",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "Golden Bridge Walking Tour",
        "sku": "walking-tour",
        "gender": false,
        "category": "All Tours",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": "27",
        "name": "Golden Bridge Private Bicycle Tour",
        "sku": "private-bicycle-tour",
        "gender": false,
        "category": "All Tours",
        "position": 2
    }],
    "categorySize": 3,
    "customerLoggedIn": 0,
    "customerId": 0,
    "customerGroupId": "1",
    "customerGroupCode": "GENERAL",
    "categoryId": "3",
    "categoryName": "All Tours",
    "pageType": "catalog\/category\/view"
})];
dataLayer.push({
    "categoryName": "All Tours Filtered",
    'ecommerce': {
        "impressions": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Golden Bridge Bicycle Tour",
            "sku": "bicycle-tour",
            "gender": false,
            "category": "All Tours",
            "position": 0
        }, {
            "id": "17",
            "name": "Golden Bridge Walking Tour",
            "sku": "walking-tour",
            "gender": false,
            "category": "All Tours",
            "position": 1
        }, {
            "id": "27",
            "name": "Golden Bridge Private Bicycle Tour",
            "sku": "private-bicycle-tour",
            "gender": false,
            "category": "All Tours",
            "position": 2
        }]
    }
});
```

let say we clicked filter and with ajax call now there are only 2 products displayed, so I want to show this in the datalayer by using this code:

```
    dataLayer.push({
    "categoryName": "All Tours Filtered 1",
    "categorySize": 2,
    "categoryProducts": [{
        "id": "33",
        "name": "Golden Bridge Segway Tour",
        "sku": "segway-tour",
        "gender": false,
        "category": "All Tours",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "Golden Bridge Walking Tour",
        "sku": "walking-tour",
        "gender": false,
        "category": "All Tours",
        "position": 1
    }],
    'ecommerce': {
        "impressions": [{
            "id": "33",
            "name": "Golden Bridge Segway Tour",
            "sku": "segway-tour",
            "gender": false,
            "category": "All Tours",
            "position": 0
        }, {
            "id": "17",
            "name": "Golden Bridge Walking Tour",
            "sku": "walking-tour",
            "gender": false,
            "category": "All Tours",
            "position": 1
        }]
    }
});
```

But instead of updating product arrays it's adding to them. And now data layer has 5 products.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataLayer.push(obj)` appends `obj` to the existing `dataLayer` without resetting it.

To reset the dataLayer use the following:

`window['google_tag_manager']['GTM-XXXXXX'].dataLayer.reset();`